# mustache template with if statemenet and constants, java

Tags: java, mustache

I've been checking the mustache documentation [here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) in order to find a way to do something like:

```
  {{#if myObj.status === "COMPLETED"}}
      <!--put this piece of code-->
  {{#/if}}

  {{#if myObj.status === "PENDING"}}
      <!--put this other piece of code instead-->
  {{#/if}}
```

However it doesn't work as handlebars do, how do I use if statements in here? and also, is it possible to set some kind of constants like:

```
 const1 = "<li>blabla</li>";
 const2 = "<li>blabla2</li>";
```

I would use them eventually into the if statements.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't `PHP` instead of `Java` ?

Comment: "We call it "logic-less" because there are no if statements, else clauses, or for loops. Instead there are only tags. Some tags are replaced with a value, some nothing, and others a series of values. This document explains the different types of Mustache tags."

**A very important quote from the documentation you linked to yourself**

Comment: yeah I get your point, however, If I need to react to diferent states, isnt it supported?

Comment: Then picking a "logic-less" thing might be a not-that-great choice. But maybe I'm just not getting it.